# How to show a pop-up message in an InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am having one InfoPath form and I am having code on VSTA project as well, now on certain condition I have to show a pop-up message in the form (I am running this form as browser enabled form). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think for your question, you can use below links will be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh278954.aspx

or

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepoint2010customization/thread/86dd8d2e-4cbf-4e28-8702-fe370b999e71

Comment: Crap - your link is a MSDN reference.  Microsoft examples suck.  They try to boil the ocean - how about a simple example to show a popup window, with hyperlinks to additional information and details how they work.